# What character is VALUE_SEPARATOR?

Tags: developer, mysql

I need to run a MySQL query to split the values in the fee_level field of the civicrm_participant table. I just can't determine what character to use as the delimiter. When I look at VALUE_SEPARATOR in eclipse, I see a character that resembles a 'binary domino.' When I look at VALUE_SEPARATOR in vi, I see ^A. I'm not sure how to query on either?

Comment: Good question. I has caught me out too. Had a dig to find my notes but didn't find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, if you use HEX() function, you can guess it's the ASCII code 01 which is not really readable :

```
MySQL> SELECT substring(besoins_sp__114, 1,1) 
       FROM civicrm_value_besoins_sp_cifiques_v_nements_26 LIMIT 1;
+---------------------------------+
| substring(besoins_sp__114, 1,1) |
+---------------------------------+
|                                |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL> SELECT HEX(substring(besoins_sp__114, 1,1)) 
       FROM civicrm_value_besoins_sp_cifiques_v_nements_26 LIMIT 1;
+--------------------------------------+
| HEX(substring(besoins_sp__114, 1,1)) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 01                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

From there, you can do reverse operation using UNHEX.
So, if you need to replace this char by another more readable one, you can do the following :

```
MySQL> SELECT replace(besoins_sp__114, UNHEX(01), '|') AS special_needs
       FROM civicrm_value_besoins_sp_cifiques_v_nements_26;
+---------------+
| special_needs |
+---------------+
| |AL|          |
| |AL|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|          |
| |VG|AL|       |
+---------------+
```

Comment: To add a little part of PHP to the excellent answer by @samuelsov: in PHP you can use the CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATOR to represent the character in question.

Comment: For more info on this CiviCRM delimiter character, see also https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=26395.0.html

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution here which I have tried and it has updated the data in the db, but currently i can't assess if the outcome was good as the site is borked at the front end for other reasons

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266517/civicrm-crm-core-daovalue-separator-how-to-use-it-in-pure-sql

so something like

```
UPDATE TABLE SET <column>=concat_ws (X'01','value1','value2','etc') WHERE id=x
```