# Updating Custom Data Fieldset Settings via php my admin

Tags: custom-fields

I've got a site where custom data has been created for Particpant records.

And the fieldsets have been made available for all event types.

The site in question relies heavily on segmenting events by type, and some of the participant fieldsets are not applicable/suitable for some event types

However the empty fieldsets are appearing in the confirmation emails for the events they are not appropriate for and causing confusion to end users.

So...My question is...
am I safe updating the values in the civicrm custom group tables for the fields
EXTENDS ENTITY COLIUMN ID
and
EXTENDS ENTITY vALUE
for the relevant data sets

I guess this is the reverse of the question asked here
[Can I change settings for a custom field set for participants without losing any data?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21500/can-i-change-settings-for-a-custom-field-set-for-participants-without-losing)

Can anyone advise me of any potential pitfalls?

Comment: I'd say that this is actually a bug. Fields should only display on the confirmation email when they have been used on the event registration form. I can't see a use case for any other behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I think you should be OK but carefully....and make sure you are not hit by any of the VALUE_SEPARATORS?

Comment: Thanks Erik, I'd seen that some of the options will need separators in place, is there guidance anywhere on how to handle these?

Comment: I think I have only done that in code, not directly in SQL....let me see

Comment: Check this one: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/what-character-is-value-separator

Comment: Will do (or at least I'll ask Jade to). Thanks Erik!